# Passing and receiving data from a module to my main application using interfaces

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, interface, module

I read (twice) this very useful article: http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/pdfs/modular.pdf

And, I know that the best way to make a connection from my main app to my modules is through interfaces.

So, my problem is, how can I implement an interface so my module can send and receive data from my main app?, because, I understand that my module implements an interface that is used by my main app.. but, can I do it "vice-versa"?

Other issue I have is, why do I need to call my main app children if I can just import a module's class?... I think this is because of the need to keep the modularity, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass in a 'bridge' interface into your 'modules' when the MainApp has created them.  This object would allow the module to call functions to send data.

So, for example, if the module interface was

```
function get name() : String 
function get version() : String
function performAction() : void // Blah blah
```

You could extend it to also include

```
function set mainAppBridge(bridge:MainAppBridge) : void
```

The MainAppBridge interface could have a method such as:

```
function receiveResult(data:Object) : void
```

After the MainApp instanciates a 'module' it will then call the `set mainAppBridge` passing in an implementation of a MainAppBridge.  The 'module' is then free to call the methods available on that bridge.

As all this is done with interfaces, you can implement the actual functionality how-ever you like.